# "Develop against" usage and meaning

Tags: word-usage, phrase-meaning, technology

I've recently come across a phrase

> *"Develop against the Sandbox and learn to use the different operators in your testing."*

It's not clear why the preposition *against* is used in this case. Can it be replaced by *in*? What is the exact meaning of *to develop against* here?

P.S. Sandbox is a simulation interface that allows to reproduce an ecosystem of an application.

Comment: @user159691 Your deleted answer may be right, but you need supporting evidence that 'against' may mean 'in the context of' in more general contexts than 'develop against a background of' ....

Comment: A Google search for "develop against" seems to give very few hits that are not false positives (examples of which could be 'Autoantibodies develop against the dermal basement membrane' and 'responses in ... patients can develop, or be induced to develop, against antigens'). Your usage may well be computer jargon.

Comment: This is a standard software term. The question I suggested as a duplicate was for *executing against*, but it is the same general idea.

Answer (score 0):

In order to measure the correctness of a software there has to be at least one known base or point to test from. So in the example above the sandbox is the known point of reference that a new software can be tested -against-.
Your question about "in":  "the software can be developed in the sandbox" has a different meaning to the original statement in which the verification of the software is the issue.

Comment: 'Develop against the sandbox' seems to correspond to 'develop against the think-tank' rather than 'develop against the proven model the think-tank came up with'.